# Send Android GPS coordinates to WebService in PHP, every 5 minutes without application Sleep

Tags: java, android, web-services, gps

I'm new in android developement.
I'm developing an application that get the current coordinates of android GPS and send it to a webservice in php who send the data (coordinates+data/time) to a MySQL data base.

Most of it is complete, the application is working and sendingo coordinates, but eventually the application sleep, as if, after 15 minutes the application stops.

Can anyone help me? here is the code:

ActivityMain.java

```
package com.example.administrador.app3;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TextView textView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationListener = new LocationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        //textView

                        double latit = location.getLatitude();
                        double longit = location.getLongitude();

                        final String lat = String.valueOf(latit);
                        final String lng = String.valueOf(longit);

                        class AddCoord extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
                            ProgressDialog loading;

                            @Override
                            protected void onPreExecute(){
                                super.onPreExecute();
                                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Adding...","Wait...",false,false);
                            }
                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                                super.onPostExecute(s);
                                loading.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            @Override
                            protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
                                HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                                params.put(Config.KEY_EMP_LAT,lat);
                                params.put(Config.KEY_EMP_LNG,lng);


                                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                                String res = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_ADD, params);
                                return res;
                            }
                        }

                        AddCoord ac = new AddCoord();
                        ac.execute();

                    }




                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {



                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {


                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                };
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                        }, 10 );
                        return;
                    }
                }else{

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 300000, 0, locationListener);

                }



            }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case 10:
                if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 300000, 0, locationListener);

        }
    }


}
```

RequestHandler.java

```
package com.example.administrador.app3;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;



public class RequestHandler {

    //Method to send httpPostRequest
    //This method is taking two arguments
    //First argument is the URL of the script to which we will send the request
    //Other is an HashMap with name value pairs containing the data to be send with the request
    public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                  HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
        //Creating a URL
        URL url;

        //StringBuilder object to store the message retrieved from the server
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            //Initializing Url
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            //Creating an httmlurl connection
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //Configuring connection properties
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            //Creating an output stream
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

            //Writing parameters to the request
            //We are using a method getPostDataString which is defined below
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                String response;
                //Reading server response
                while ((response = br.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(response);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String sendGetRequest(String requestURL){
        StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestURL);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String s;
            while((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(s+"\n");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String sendGetRequestParam(String requestURL, String id){
        StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestURL+id);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String s;
            while((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(s+"\n");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Config.java

```
package com.example.administrador.app3;


public class Config {
    public static final String URL_ADD = "***my_url_page_with_the_php_code***";

    //keys that will be used to send the request to php scripts
    public static final String KEY_EMP_LAT = "lat";
    public static final String KEY_EMP_LNG = "lng";


}
```

Thank you beforehand!

Comment: in the title i mean "every 5 minutes"

Comment: you can edit title to prevent misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are getting location updates from your activity but when your phone goes to sleep your activity will be stopped and hence the updates will be stopped.

You need to use the `PendingIntent` version of the `requestLocationUpdates()` method. Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

> This method is suited for the background use cases, more specifically for receiving location updates, even when the app has been killed by the system.

You'll have to make an `IntentService` or a `BroadcastReceiver` to keep getting the location updates.

Comment: sorry i'm really new in android developement,

Comment: may I to replace the LocationListener for BroadcastReceiver in the code?

Comment: Yes, that's what you have to do.